# Am I allowed to post the URL of the site I need help with?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, external-links

Let's say I have a problem, but I can't get a fiddle going. Is it against the rules to link the actual source?

For example, with my website, I'm having an issue that's sort of complex, and I can't replicate in a fiddle. Will I get downvoted or banned if I ask people to look at my site to see the issue?

Comment: *I can't get a fiddle going* - Despite what some users will tell you in the comments, you don't actually have to provide a link to a fiddle, you just need to provide the code. Even if you do create a fiddle, you have to put the code in the question itself. The fiddle just makes it easier for other users to help you but someone else can create one (if it's doable at all) if you provide the code for a MCVE.

Comment: ... and, you can use Stack Snippets to do pretty much anything jsfiddle.net can do :).

Answer (score 16):

You presumably would like to fix your site once you know what the problem is. After you do that, what use would the question be to anyone else?

You need to take the time to create a minimal example. Cut your site down one bit at a time till you get there and then put that in the question.